# How do I have master details page and a back button on single page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have app where in I have master details page something like this:[image: img]
I would have this(left menu bar settings, login) static for all the pages. Since I am using master details page I am using messagingcenter to navigate between pages as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172577/xamarin-forms-with-masterdetails-page-and-navigation):

```
MessagingCenter.Send(new RedirectClass.OpenDetails(), RedirectClass.OpenDetails.Key);
```

But now since I have used master details I cannot  navigate back using back button. The back button would exit the application. Say user is at 'page A', When user clicks on settings menu the user should be redirected to settings page(settings page will all have left menu), so on click of back button on settings page should redirect user to 'Page A'. Which is not happening. ANy help?

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<RedirectClass.OpenDetails>(this, RedirectClass.OpenDetails.Key, (sender) =>
            {
                Detail = new NavigationPage(new Details())
                {
                    BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(172, 183, 193),
                    BarTextColor = Color.Black,
                    BackgroundColor = Color.White
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding the Detail page in your MessagingCenter callback

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(new Details())
```

You should use the Detail page's Navigation property to push the new page on the top of the stack

```
Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Details())
```

make sure your initial detail page is wrapped in a navigationpage

Comment: That doesn't give me the top hamburger icon.. instead it shows a back icon

Comment: Oh, okay, you can do that as well. In that case wrap the MainPage (master detail) into a navigation page, and you can push a new master detail page (with master set to the same screen as always and detail set to whatever detail you want to show) to the MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync().

Comment: @irreal could you please provide an example of this?

Comment: @irreal Don't worry, managed to sort this. For anyone else, to keep the hamburger instead of a back button, use the following:  App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage { Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType)) };

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, `Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(itemSelected)` makes **hamburger** menu *vanish* I decided to use my own stack datatype for Master detail page. It was bit tricky to keep track and code but working fine.

Initialize it at the app load with current Detail page and for each item selected Push new page on top of stack.

```
public partial class MyMasterDetailPage: MasterDetailPage
    {
        private Stack navigationStack = new Stack();
        public MyMasterDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            navigationStack.Push(Detail);
            try
            {
                masterPage.listView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }

        }
```

Override `OnBackButtonPressed()` in same Page code behind

```
        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            try
            {
                var lastPage = navigationStack.Pop();
                if (lastPage.Equals(Detail))
                    lastPage = navigationStack.Pop();

                Detail = (Page)lastPage;
                IsPresented = false;

               // to avoid app close when complete pop and new page is push on top of it 
                if (navigationStack.Count == 0) 
                    navigationStack.Push(Detail);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            }
        }
```